# Multivariable non-linear fitting

Tags: fitting, modeling

I have a function called "C" that I know it depends on 6 variable. I have a set of data points, 6 rows by 9 columns, in which in each row only one variable is changing and the rest of the variables are constant.

I was able to fit each row independently (one variable fitting and modeling) and I double checked on excel as shown below:

[image]

I would like to ask about the best way of fitting the function "C" as a function of all the 6 variables into a single equation.

For the single variable fitting, this is the code I used:

```
    data1 = {{2, 4.8128*10^-12}, {3, 7.5623*10^-12}, {4, 
   9.9060*10^-12}, {5, 1.1378*10^-11}, {6, 1.3474*10^-11}, {7, 
   1.5636*10^-11}, {8, 1.7803*10^-11}, {9, 2.0028*10^-11}, {10, 
   2.2438*10^-11}}; (* x1 and C data pairs*)
g1 = ListPlot[data1] 
g2 = LinearModelFit[data1, x, x] 

g22 = Normal[g2] 
Show[Plot[g22, {x, 2, 10}], g1] 
g2["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable" ]
```

Comment: Can you give us the full data set ?

Comment: @Lotus Sure, you can find the excel sheet in the following link. I also added the .nb file in which the whole data set is typed in a suitable format for mathematica:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B86yrioiczo4WXJycG5idzl1VUE

Comment: What kind of basis functions are you looking for ? Polynomials ? Trig functions ?

Comment: @Lotus Polynomials, powers and possibly logarithms

Comment: The syntax itself is quite straightforward. For example I go with

Comment: NonlinearModelFit[data7, 
 a x1 + b x2 + c x3 + d x4 + e x5 + f x6, {a, b, c, d, e, f}, {x1, x2,
   x3, x4, x5, x6}] to get a fitted function, but its probably a bad fit. If you know what form of the fit fiction you are looking for, I am sure you can get a good fit.

Comment: @Lotus is there a way to know how good my fit is? For single variable functions, plotting is very convenient and straightforward,however, I am not sure how to check the accuracy of the fit in the multi-variable functions

Comment: Oh..its a whole subject in its own right. You will have to study it in some detail. Googling it gives you a bunch of articles. This can be a start.

Comment: @Lotus Thank you. I found that this option "StandardizedResiduals" helps in giving a rough idea how good the fit is. It compares the fitted vs. actual data points (in my case 54 data points) using the standard error calculation for each of the points. Will try to improve my methodology.

Comment: You state that "the rest of the variables are constant".  At what values are they held constant?  One would need to know this to construct the data points {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,c} which would give you 54 data points.  (If the 9 measurements are on the same experimental unit, then you really have a repeated measures situation which as far as I know, *Mathematica* does not yet handle directly.)

Comment: @JimBaldwin at each row, only one variable changes. All variables values are known. You can find the full data set here in the word file specifically: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B86yrioiczo4WXJycG5idzl1VUE&usp=drive_web

Comment: I built a model like `model = a1 x1 + a2 Log[x2] + a3 x3^-b3 + a4 x4 +  a5 x5 + a6 x6^2 + 
  b6 x6 + offset` using the form for the individual components and ran `NonlinearModelFit`. It yielded an answer but did not fit the data. This makes it appear that there is some interaction between the various inputs. Do you have any physics behind the data that might suggest a form for the model?

Comment: Can you check these two items out. In the third group (`data7[[19;;27]]`) the second input has a value of 0.0015 rather than 0.001 for the groups one and four through six. `data[[7,5]]` has the same inputs as `data[[7,37]]` but a very different measurement. I don't know whether this is the actual data with errors are some copy and paste mistake.

Comment: Also `data[[7,5]]` and `data7[[48]]` have the same inputs and different outputs. `data[[7,5]]` is supposed to represent the constant parameter case.

Comment: @JackLaVigne Thanks Jack for your comments and answer. I just saw them! Will check all you comments and answer and get back to you soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have copied the data from your notebook and would like to share some information.

### Fit Individual Components

In order to facilitate the fitting and plotting I created groups of six {x,y} pairs, one group for each of the six variables.

```
dataGroup = 
  Map[Transpose@
     Join[{data7[[1 + (# - 1)*9 ;; #*9, #]], 
       data7[[1 + (# - 1)*9 ;; #*9, 7]]}] &, Range[6]];

varNames = {"Fingers", "Width", "Spacing", "Length", "Gap", 
   "Thickness"};
```

Next fit the individual groups using the models from your spreadsheet.

```
model = ConstantArray[0, 6]; param = ConstantArray[0, 6]; sol = 
 ConstantArray[0, 6];

model[[1]] = a1 x + b1; param[[1]] = {a1, b1};
model[[2]] = a2 Log[x] + b2; param[[2]] = {a2, b2};
model[[3]] = a3 x^-b3; param[[3]] = {a3, b3};
model[[4]] = a4 x + b4; param[[4]] = {a4, b4};
model[[5]] =  a5 x + b5; param[[5]] = {a5, b5};
model[[6]] = a6 x^2 + b6 x + c6; param[[6]] = {a6, b6, c6};
```

Use `FindFit` along with the arrays just created.

```
(sol[[#]] = 
    FindFit[dataGroup[[#]], model[[#]], param[[#]], x]) & /@ Range[6]
(* {{a1 -> 2.1325*10^-12, b1 -> 8.7591*10^-13},
    {a2 -> 2.65771*10^-12, b2 -> 3.22181*10^-11},
    {a3 -> 7.84083*10^-13, b3 -> 0.413135},
    {a4 -> 3.69143*10^-10, b4 -> -2.19223*10^-13},
    {a5 -> -6.16*10^-11, b5 -> 1.4081*10^-11},
    {a6 -> 4.59524*10^-6, b6 -> 2.38786*10^-9, c6 -> 1.20616*10^-11}} *)
```

Plot the results

```
Grid@Partition[Module[
     {
      fun = model[[#]] /. sol[[#]],
      xmin = Min[dataGroup[[#, All, 1]]],
      xmax = Max[dataGroup[[#, All, 1]]]
      },
     Show[
      ListPlot[
       dataGroup[[#]],
       PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red},
       PlotLabel -> varNames[[#]]
       ],
      Plot[fun, {x, xmin, xmax}, PlotStyle -> Black],
      PlotRange -> All,
      ImageSize -> 300
      ]
     ] & /@ Range[6],
  2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Data problems

When an attempt was made to fit the data in one fell swoop, problems arose. This is due to three problems in the data.

Presumably all the variables were held constant and one allowed to vary in each of the six groups.

The constant inputs I will call the center point and equal:

```
data7[[5]]
(* {6, 1/1000, 1/1000, 19/500, 1/500, 1/5000, 1.3474*10^-11} *)
```

The first problem was relatively minor. For variable three (Spacing) the value of variable two (Width) is 0.0015 when it should have been 0.001.

More serious problems are present for variable five (Gap) and variable six (Thickness). They have the same input variables but a radically different capacitance.

```
{data7[[5]], data7[[37]], data7[[48]]}
(* {{6, 1/1000, 1/1000, 19/500, 1/500, 1/5000, 1.3474*10^-11},
    {6, 1/1000, 1/1000, 19/500, 1/500, 1/5000, 1.3948*10^-11},
    {6, 1/1000, 1/1000, 19/500, 1/500, 1/5000, 1.2764*10^-11}} *)
```

New synthetic data was created from the existing data and repaired using these steps:

**group 3 (Spacing**) - make variable 2 = 1/1000 and subtract from `y` so that it matches at the center

**group 5 (Gap)** - subtract from the y values so that there is a match at the center point

**group 6 (Thickness)** - add to the y values so that there is a match at the center point

```
dataF = data7;
dataF[[19 ;; 27, 2]] = 1/1000;
dataF[[19 ;; 27, 7]] = data7[[19;;27,7]] + (data7[[5,7]] - data7[[19,7]]);
dataF[[37 ;; 45, 7]] = data7[[37;; 45,7]] + (data7[[5,7]] - data7[[37,7]]);
dataF[[46 ;; 54, 7]] = data7[[46;;54,7]] + (data7[[5,7]] - data7[[48,7]]);

dataGroupF = 
  Map[Transpose@
     Join[{dataF[[1 + (# - 1)*9 ;; #*9, #]], 
       dataF[[1 + (# - 1)*9 ;; #*9, 7]]}] &, Range[6]];
```

### Fit all of the data using center point

Fit the data in one fell swoop by using the form for the individual components and deviations from the center point. `FindFit` and `NonlinearModelFit` have the same input form. The latter produces a ***FittedModel*** and provides statistical information on the parameters.

Note: I am not recommending that this be the final solution. It would be **much** better if a valid theoretical model could be found.

My purpose here is to show the mechanics of how to optimize all of the data.

```
xF = data7[[5, 1 ;; 6]]; yF = data7[[5, 7]];

modelF = a1 (x1 - xF[[1]]) + a2 (Log[x2] - Log[xF[[2]]]) + 
   a3 (1/x3^b3 - 1/xF[[3]]^b3) + a4 (x4 - xF[[4]]) + 
   a5 (x5 - xF[[5]]) + a6 (x6 - xF[[6]])^2 + b6 (x6 - xF[[6]]) + yF;
```

Use `NonlinearModelFit`

```
solF = NonlinearModelFit[dataF, modelF, 
   paramF, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}];

(* {{a1 -> 2.1325*10^-12}, {a2 -> 2.94108*10^-12},
    {a3 -> 1.12959*10^-13, b3 -> 0.657385},
    {a4 -> 3.7597*10^-10}, {a5 -> -6.07353*10^-11},
    {a6 -> 3.88793*10^-6, b6 -> 4.23126*10^-9}} *)
```

Now plot the results

```
Grid@Partition[Module[
     {
      args = xF,
      xmin = Min[dataGroupF[[#, All, 1]]],
      xmax = Max[dataGroupF[[#, All, 1]]]
      },

     args[[#]] = x;

     Show[
      ListPlot[
       dataGroupF[[#]],
       PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red},
       PlotLabel -> varNames[[#]]
       ],
      ListPlot[{{xF[[#]], yF}}, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Blue}],
      Plot[solF[Sequence @@ args], {x, xmin, xmax}, 
       PlotStyle -> Black],
      PlotRange -> All,
      ImageSize -> 300
      ]
     ] & /@ Range[6],
  2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Information on the parameters

```
solF["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a million for the very detailed comment and very nice explanation!
Regarding the problems of the data:
1. (Spacing) Problem:that was a typo. I later found out. You are right it should be 0.001
2. (Gap) and (Thickness) Problem: You are absolutely right. These are actually simulation results. I have to double check my simulation for the (Gap) and (Thickness) parts as I am sure about the data of what you have called(center point).
The rest of you explanation is quite clear, and the flow of the work is clear as well except from some of the code syntax which I am not very familiar with.

Comment: Regarding you suggestion of working out a theoretical equation, as far as I am familiar with the subject, it is possible at certain relative dimensions. For the relative dimensions I am working on, mostly fringing and higher order effects play important roles. That's why I am going for regression.

On another note: Is what you have called (Center Point Method) a well-known and a documented method in the literature?  If yes, can you please guide me to a reference where I can read about this and other used methods?

I am really thankful for your contribution.